# Java code to webservice

Tags: java, web-services

I have written a piece of Java code which I am suppose to expose as a webservice and then later it will be consumed by Coldfusion 9.

Could anyone please give me some pointer for how to convert my Java code as a webservice?

Comment: first tell us what exactly have you done it

Comment: What kind of web service? SOAP? REST? XML over HTTP? JSON?

Comment: My code is to do some video transcoing which will then be used by the frontend developed in coldfusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many options, among them are Axis2 with its java2wsdl. There is also springWS.

Personally I prefer axis2 for writing clients and SpringWS for writing the actual web service.

Comment: I am using axis2 with tomcat server. Works fine. Lots of information online. Thanks for heads up :)

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look here, it is pretty easy to annotate a façade to your service and expose it as a webservice:
http://cxf.apache.org/